# Image at center

Tags: html, css

I am coding a website in which I want the image to be in the center at all size of screens.

I tried:-

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator");
            var images = rotator.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for (var i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
                images[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            var counter = 1;
            setInterval(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    images[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                images[counter].style.display = "block";
                counter++;
                if (counter == images.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }, 1000);
        };
    </script>
 <style>
 .pg{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
 }
 img
{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div class="pg" id="rotator">
        <img alt="" src="img/logo.png" />
        <img alt="" src="img/aip.png" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code couldn't give me success.

Please help me out!

Please share your codes for the same.

I am not able to center the image with my code so please help me out.

CSS is:-

```
<style>
    .pg{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
    }
    img
{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
    </style>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) will help.

Comment: Try adding position:absolute in your css style for pg class.

Comment: You need to apply css on img. Use following css: <style>
 .pg img{
    margin: auto;    
 }
 </style>

Comment: @SAJ then it image is not in the center.

Comment: Have you tried margin:auto on img tag? First remove the css you have written already, It may create a problem.

Comment: @ArunKumarSaini I have tried but it didn't help me. I have edited the question and snippet.

Comment: Remove complete css and use  <style> .pg img{ margin: auto; } </style>.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display horizontally and vertically center try this:
i have put height,width and border to make it more understandable.
for different screen sizes you have to specify image width accordingly using media query.

```js
window.onload = function () {
            var rotator = document.getElementById("rotator");
            var images = rotator.getElementsByTagName("img");
            for (var i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
                images[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            var counter = 1;
            setInterval(function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    images[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                images[counter].style.display = "block";
                counter++;
                if (counter == images.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }, 1000);
        };
```

```css
.pg {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}
img {
       width:80px;
    }
```

```html
    <form id="form1">
    <div class="pg" id="rotator">
      <div class="img" id="rotator">
        <img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBxRp.png" />
        <img alt="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GIJP.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It helped me somewhere, bu I need full page not some part of the page

Comment: remove height,border in .pg and remove img width

Comment: doing that image from sides go out of the browser when we resize the browser width.

Comment: i think you should specify either height or width to image

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    img
    {
      display:block;
      margin:auto;
      max-width:100%;
    }
```

all images are center aligned.

Comment: but when we resize the browser, it doesn't help

Comment: https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/MowYVp   here is a reference link

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center;` to `pg` class and add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `img` tags.

```
.pg {
  text-align: center;
}

.pg img{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/168e2n8t/)